# How to apply css to html code when we are using in ckeditor

Tags: html, ckeditor

I have added background color to `th` in the below table it is working fine normally. But, if we use same code in `ckeditor` the style is not applying

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5" style="text-align:center;
               background: green;color:#fff;">SPECIAL CLASSES TIME TABLE
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create css class of your applied style and setting the contentCss of ckedior as below

```
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/mycustom.css';
```